# Mysql questions about separated indexes for several columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

if you can help me based on your experience to answer these questions about these questions

1-  if I created separated indexes for 5 columns

username,country,created_at,comment,status

and used many columns in where clause   username='' and country = '' and comments = ''

will the sql use  indexes for these 3 columns ? since each one has it's own index.

2-  if I have multi columns index  "username,country,created_at,comment,status"

and I used 2 columns   where username = '' and status = ''

I know it will use username, but will it use index for status  as well?

Comment: Check the execution plans.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-index-merge-join-type.html

Comment: mysql doc is so good but it has one issue  like the url you added  it doesn't  add tables and real examples also  doesn't show  which columns has index ....   that is way it looks complicated a little bit.  Thank you for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL almost never uses 2 indexes in a single query.  (That is, "index merge" is almost never chosen by the Optimizer.)

A 'composite' (multi-column) index, when appropriate, is better than two separate indexes.

```
WHERE username = '...' and country = '...' and comment = '...'
```

will usually benefit from

```
INDEX(username, country, comments) -- in any order
```

For that `WHERE`, `INDEX(username, country, created_at, comment, status)` will be use only the first two columns.  (Unless it is 'covering'.)

```
WHERE username = '' and status = ''
```

Will benefit from any index *starting* with *both* `username` and `status` in *either* order.  It will *partially* benefit from the 5-column composite index above -- the first column, `username`.  It will use `status` only if 'covering'.

A "covering" index is an that contains *all* the columns used *anywhere* in the `SELECT` query.  Having the right columns in the right order in an `INDEX` is more important than 'covering'.

Here's [*my discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on how to create optimal indexes.